# Complexity time needed for any algorithm

Tags: complexity-theory, reference-request

How to understand at least a small introduction to the complexity time for algorithm , how i can know that algorithm need O(log^2 N ) and so on is there any basic reference for this topic , needed in my project

Comment: I can't understand what you're question is.

Comment: im not computer science student  i need to understand the idea of complexity of any algorithm since its needed in my project (thesis).
in number theory . 
im preparing a paper in primality testing algorithms and paper will based on the complexity time needed to prove which algorithm is faster and efficient

Comment: Any good textbook on algorithms will include a section on analysis.